# PHP only sending the first word in my sentense?

Tags: php

I am developing an APi where its suppossed to send a text message to a number ...this should be the message "**Your registration for mobile Number has been received. Thank you for staying connected**" but the text massage that is sending is only the first word "**Your**"

here is my code

```
    $message ="Your registration for mobile no has been received. Thank you for staying with MbongoCash";

sendTextMessage("0719401837",$message);

function sendTextMessage($phoneNumber,$data)
{

    $url = "http://121.241.242.114/bulksms/bulksms?username=josy-mbongocash&password=Jofar14&type=0&dlr=1&destination=$phoneNumber&source=MbongoCash&message='$data''";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Here is the image.
[This is the Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfKDZ.png)

Comment: Maybe all space needs to be replaced with `%20` as you send them with get?

Comment: Try [`urlencode()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the spaces with %20.

```
$message ="Your registration for mobile no has been received. Thank you for staying with MbongoCash";
$message =str_replace(" ", "%20", $message);
// rest of code.
```

Answer (score 4):

The spaces in the message break the URL. Using [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) should solve this:

```
$data = urlencode($data);
```

Comment: This anwer is better than the accepted answer of andreas, as this one converts every url-unsafe character to url-save characters